# How to get 'man' working in an Alpine Linux Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, manpage, alpine-linux

I can’t get `man` to work in an Alpine Linux Docker container.

Pull Alpine Linux and start a container.

```
docker pull alpine:latest
docker run -t -i alpine /bin/ash
```

Update repository indexes from all remote repositories.

```
apk update
```

Install `man` and `man-pages`.

```
apk add man man-pages
```

Install a package and its documentation.

```
apk add curl
apk add curl-doc
```

Try to view the man pages.

```
/ # man curl
/usr/share/man/mandoc.db: No such file or directory
man: outdated mandoc.db lacks curl(1) entry,
     consider running  # makewhatis /usr/share/man
more: -s: No such file or directory
/ #
```

What?

---

**Update**

Following @EugenMayer’s advice to add `mdicml-apropos`, I can get `curl --manual` to work but not `man curl`. Unfortunately, `gnupg --manual` doesn’t work at all. This behaviour is inconsistent and unexpected.

Comment: I would suggest not to install man or any other extra packages which will make it larger image. The Alpine docker came into picture due to lightweight containerization. So, just install required packages or use official Alpine images (httpd,tomcat,java, etc) you can refer man pages from your local Linux based machine.

Comment: Fair enough. I’m actually trying to create my own containered GnuPG environment. In the process of learning, `man ...` is sometimes more insightful than `... --help`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
apk add mdocml-apropos
```

and then for each package you need the man packages for

```
apk add curl-doc
```

and you are set to go to use man after, like you already did

```
apk add man man-pages mdocml-apropos
```

The source for this (plus added the mdocml-apropos which is missing there) is https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#Why_don.27t_I_have_man_pages_or_where_is_the_.27man.27_command.3F but interstingly, i cannot get it working myself.

Also tried to `export TERM=xterm` to see if thats in `iteractivity` issue but it is not.

Also tried `makewhatis /usr/share/man` manually, but no sucess.

Interestingly though:

```
ls  -la /usr/share/man/man1/curl-config.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1687 Aug  4 15:07 /usr/share/man/man1/curl-config.1.gz
```

So there is a manpage

Comment: There’s also a shortcut – if you want to install -doc subpackage for each package, run `apk add docs`.

Comment: I tried this and `curl --manual` works but not `man curl`. Unfortunately, `gnupg --manual` doesn’t work at all.

Comment: @JakubJirutka Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 5):

For me, to get rid of this error:

```
man man
more: -s: No such file or directory
```

I use:

```
export PAGER=less
```

then it works

Comment: Alternatively, you can install `util-linux`, but yeah, I like `less` `more` :)

Comment: Your answer does not help people like me who want to install the man package.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a pretty old question, however I'm going to post my answer anyway, maybe it could be useful for someone else in the future.
I tried the solution for *Alpine Linux v3.15* Docker container and it works.

##### Steps to reproduce:

1. `docker pull alpine:3.15`
2. `docker run --rm --name alpine -it alpine:3.15 /bin/sh`
3. `apk add curl`
4. `apk add curl-doc`
5. typing `man curl`, you will obtain the following error:

   ```
   /bin/sh: man: not found
   ```
6. In order to resolve the above error, type: `apk add mandoc man-pages`
7. You should be able to view and browse the `curl`'s manual page!

In case you still face an error, type the following command: `export PAGER=less` and then try to look `curl`'s manual page up again.

Additional resources: [Install `man` in an alpine linux docker container](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-install-man-pages-in-alpine-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this has to do with the way you are connected to the container. I'm using alpine a lot with LXD, and generally can't read any man page when connected via `lxc exec container ash`. I suppose docker connect you to the container the same way.

```
$ lxc exec alp03 ash
~ # man man
more: -s: No such file or directory
```

So you can use `su -`, and then you will be able to use man:

```
~ # su -
alp03:~# man man
MAN(1P)                    POSIX Programmer's Manual
(...)
```

Note how the prompt is different after the `su -` command.

Also, if I run a ssh server inside the container and then connect to this container via ssh, then man is working perfectly.